# HIBERNATE Unidirectional ManyToMany delete problem

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a problem deleting an entity
I have tariffs their options and contract that saves info about some chosen options (It means that for example tariff has 3 options and contract has to store first and third options), and I want contract to save options permanently or at least don't fall when I delete option, I use ManyToMany annotation to create table Contract_Options where I can store chosen ones, but I have already tried @OnDelete() and @Cascade and cascade inside @ManyToMany still get error, I DONT WANT to bidirectional relation I mean I want options not to know anything about contracts, here is the code:

My Contract entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "contract")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Contract {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "phone_number")
    private Long phoneNumber;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE})
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.NO_ACTION)
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Options> chosenOptions;

    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.REFRESH},fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "tariff_id")
    private Tariff tariff;

}
```

My Option Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "options")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Options {

    public Options(int id, String name, OptionType optionType, Double cost, Tariff tariff) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.optionType = optionType;
        this.cost = cost;
        this.tariff = tariff;
    }

    public Options(String name, OptionType optionType,Double cost, Tariff tariff) {
        this.name = name;
        this.optionType = optionType;
        this.cost = cost;
        this.tariff = tariff;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "option_type")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private OptionType optionType;

    @Column(name = "cost")
    private Double cost;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) //change LAZY if not works
    @JoinColumn(name = "tariff_id")
    private Tariff tariff;
}
```

Just a simple code in Main.java

```
        User user = new User("log","1",Role.ADMIN);
        userDao.save(user);
        List<Options> options = new ArrayList<>();

        Tariff tariff = new Tariff();
        options.add(new Options("da",OptionType.INTERNET,1D,tariff));
        options.add(new Options("net",OptionType.INTERNET,1D,tariff));

        tariff.setTitle("tariff");
        tariff.setCost(1d);
        tariff.setDescription("ddd");
        tariff.setOptions(options);

        tariffDao.addTariff(tariff);


        List<Options> updatedOptions = Collections.singletonList(tariffDao.findTariffById(1).getOptions().get(0));

        Contract contract= new Contract(1,87770011098L,user, updatedOptions,tariff);

        contractDao.save(contract);

        Contract contract2= new Contract(2,87770011098L,user, updatedOptions,tariff);

        contractDao.save(contract2);

        optionsDao.deleteOptionById(1); //here I get ERROR
```

Error:

```
Hibernate: delete from options where id=?
2022-03-04 21:42:01 WARN  SqlExceptionHelper:129 - SQL Error: 1451, SQLState: 23000
2022-03-04 21:42:01 ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:131 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`javaschooldb`.`contract_options`, CONSTRAINT `FKp6qx4uaj6ow16cj0h3vnyuc8v` FOREIGN KEY (`chosenOptions_id`) REFERENCES `options` (`id`))
2022-03-04 21:42:01 INFO  AbstractBatchImpl:193 - HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
2022-03-04 21:42:01 ERROR ExceptionMapperStandardImpl:39 - HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement]
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1434)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:484)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3190)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2404)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:467)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:68)
    at ru.javaSchoolProject.dao.OptionsDao.deleteOptionById(OptionsDao.java:35)
    at Main.main(Main.java:83)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3313)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3550)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityDeleteAction.execute(EntityDeleteAction.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:586)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:460)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1428)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`javaschooldb`.`contract_options`, CONSTRAINT `FKp6qx4uaj6ow16cj0h3vnyuc8v` FOREIGN KEY (`chosenOptions_id`) REFERENCES `options` (`id`))
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:117)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:974)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1113)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1061)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1381)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1046)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
    ... 19 more
```

I use hibernate + spring if it's necessary

To sum up the question is at least hoe to get rid of this error, but the wanted result is not to delete chosen option if the parent option is deleted

Comment: It isn't clear what you want. Maybe spell out a bit more detail on what you want to happen and what you are doing exactly. What do you think *should* happen when you try to delete option 1? What happens to the contract java instance which still has a reference to that now deleted Option? 
PS, the cascade option only affect what happens to referenced options when you delete a Contract instance. They do not tell or affect what happens when an option is deleted.

Comment: If all you want is to be able to execute a delete operation and damn the consequences - issue a native query to delete from the relation table all rows referencing option 1 before issuing the deleteOptionById query, in the same transaction. Two separate back to back queries in the same method/operation/transaction. Option knows nothing about the constraints referencing it by your own design, so you must find other ways to clean up any errant pointers.

Comment: @Chris yeah u got it right all I want is to set constraint to a foreign key (chosenOption_id -> options(id) ) ON DELETE NO ACTION  but its impossible with hibernate, thanks for info about cascade, I'll try to write my own queries mb will set to null, if it works it would be great

Comment: Hibernate/JPA does not allow specifying the ON DELETE cascade option (which is what you really want) on the FK to the Option in the relation table that is generated for the ManyToMany in the database. That is why you shouldn't rely entirely on such features - get the script and edit it to match what you really want. Adding it to the DB will avoid the need for the manual query when deleting options. But you still have to deal with the inconsistencies of your Java classes. Contact will have options within its collection that may no longer exist, and will cause problems if you attempt to save.

Comment: @Chris, thanks for help, I decided to do it in another way so I don't have to worry about FK